# How can I use GPU on an iMac to train a Tensorflow / LSTM / Keras script?

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

As you know Apple uses Radeon on iMac's. I have been trying to find out a solution to speed up the training process and no luck so far!

So can you pros direct me to the right route on this? I mean can i already use GPU on my iMac without adding any equipments or shall i go and buy some external NVIDIA and Thunderbolt box?

I am planning to use Tensorflowi keras aand sklearn on my iMac macOS High Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

Supporting Radeon and OpenCL is an ongoing issue in tensorflow
you can check the issue on github there are some workarounds and tensorflow forks that support that.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22

Answer (score 0):

[tf-coriander](https://github.com/hughperkins/tf-coriander)(tensorflow 1.11 modified) support macOS AMD GPUS!
Proven on my MBP2017 AMD Radeon 560